# How to Reload the items after searching in listview

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, listview, search

I want to Search in a list view i c#  when i write something in search box  my text appear in list view and show me the items which i need  but when i remove the text from search textbox i cannot see my old data which were in the list view my code is:

```
 private bool ItemMatches(ListViewItem item, string text)
        {
        bool matches = false;
        matches |= item.Text.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower());
        if (matches)
        {
            return true;
        }
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems)
        {
            matches |= subitem.Text.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower());
            if (matches)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.BeginUpdate();

            // restore all items in case user deletes some characters in the textbox
         //   ReinitList();

            string search = textBox4.Text;
            // Search items in our Jobs ListView, remove those that do not match search
            if (search != String.Empty)
            {
                for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    ListViewItem currentItem = listView1.Items[i];
                    if (ItemMatches(currentItem, search))
                    {
                        // highlight, or move highlighting to ItemMatches
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            listView1.EndUpdate();
        }
```

Comment: you are removing item. Once removed, you're done. Try to keep items in a list and then add them back

Comment: how will i do it can you explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this working program. It does what you asked for using list collection. All you need is to add your subitem search logic and it will do what you expect

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<ListViewItem> _items = new List<ListViewItem>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView1.Columns.Add("Col 1");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col 2");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Col 3");
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        _items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "a item", "some text aaa-contained", "dfsdfsdf 3a sfdfsgerrge" }));
        _items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "b item", "some text bbb-contained", "xcvcxbxcv 3b 56756855" }));
        _items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "c item", "some text ccc-contained", "wefweferbtr 3c yjyuk" }));
        _items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "d item", "some text ddd-contained", "ghjghkghgh 3d 5675675uytry" }));
        _items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "e item", "some text eee-contained", "sdfasdfwewer 3e hgytuiti" }));

        listView1.Items.AddRange(_items.ToArray());
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            listView1.Items.AddRange(_items.ToArray());
            return;
        }
        var searchResults = _items.Where(item => AnyOfTheItemsContainAGivenText(item, textBox1.Text));
        listView1.Items.AddRange(searchResults.ToArray());
    }


    private bool AnyOfTheItemsContainAGivenText(ListViewItem item, string text)
    {

        if (item.Text.IndexOf(text, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
            return true;
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems)
        {
            if (subitem.Text.IndexOf(text, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is perfect but it search just index 0 item i want to search 5th  index item then what i do and the second thing is when i modified the data then it shows me extra entry how to remove that modified entry from array

Comment: @irfankhan I thought, you will be glad that I left for you last piece of functionality to claim the fame. I only showed you the principal idea.

Comment: dear the main problem is that i did not get that from where this (item.text) came from i want to search on column which is 'Name so how to search on that colum my main problems is this'

Comment: you comment in the code that "add subitem search" so i want to add sub item [5] search just tell me that line of code i will i do it Thanks in advance

Comment: @irfankhan Ok. I improved my program to search all columns

Comment: @irfankhan Not sure what do you mean but the improved version is in the answer

Comment: mean which can search all the columns

Comment: share that program if possible which can search all the column Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry i cant see the new code i saw now thanks you so much i m going to try this

Comment: Thank you sir its working. Thumbs up for you. you are the real programmer

Comment: @irfankhan well, yea. I am :-). Please accept and upvote my answer, since you're happy with it. Thanks